# How can I get the raw value of a text node?

Tags: javascript, dom-node

Let's say I have the following:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "&lt;";
    var nodes = div.childNodes;
    console.log(nodes)
```

then in all fields of `nodes[0]` (i.e. `nodes[0].data`, `nodes[0].nodeValue`, `nodes[0].textContent`, `nodes[0].wholeText`) I get `<`. **Can I retrieve the "raw" value of a text node somehow?** In this case `&lt;`. Or is the only option to first retrieve it parsed, and then to escape the html somewhat like this:

```
function escapeHtml(html) {
    var text = document.createTextNode(html);
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(text);
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Note: I consciously chose `childNodes` in order to get text-nodes as well as non-text-nodes.

Comment: The raw text data *is* `<`. If you want to get the value with the entities that you assigned, just don't assign it but use the string directly (or retrieve it as `div.innerHTML` from where you assigned it).

Comment: What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Your example is pretty contrived.

Comment: great question. the problem is even worse when you have &lrm;  then you dont get it back at all